# Are logarithms of prime numbers algebraically independent?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, prime-numbers, logarithms, transcendence-theory

From [Baker's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem) it follows that a linear combination of [natural logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) of [prime numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) with non-zero [algebraic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number) coefficients can never be zero.

Has it been proved that the set of all natural logarithms of prime numbers is [algebraically independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence) over [$\mathbb Q$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number)?

In other words, can we be sure that expressions like the following are never exactly zero?
$$\frac{347}{75}\,\ln^22\cdot\ln3-\frac{173}{100}\,\ln2\cdot\ln^23+\frac{179}{180}\,\ln^32-\ln^33$$

Comment: As the article you link to states, next to nothing is known about this sort of question: "so far it remains to be proved that there even exist two algebraic numbers whose logarithms are algebraically independent."

Comment: As far as I know this is an open problem, but like many open problems of this form it follows from Schanuel's conjecture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture).