# $\ln p$ are algebraically independent over $\Bbb Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Is the set $S:=\{\ln p \mid p\ \text{is prime}\}$ is algebraically independent over $\Bbb Q$? i.e. if $t_1 \lt t_2 \lt \cdots \lt t_n \in S$, then $f(t_1,t_2,\cdots ,t_n) \neq 0$ for all nonzero polynomials $f \in \Bbb Q [X_1,X_2, \cdots,X_n]$ ?

Comment: Looking at the comments to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375825/are-logarithms-of-prime-numbers-algebraically-independent) and at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem#Extensions), it appears that not even the *existence* of two prime numbers $p_1,p_2$ such that $\ln p_1$ and $\ln p_2$ are algebraically independent has yet been proved.

Comment: @G. Sassatelli Now I've read the wiki's description. The Japanese wiki does not refer to this... Thank you for your comment!