# Two different rational numbers to the power irrational both rational

Tags: exponentiation, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I'm trying to generalize the question [Is there such an $x$ that both $2^{\frac{x}{3}}$ and $3^{\frac{x}{2}}$ are simultaneously rational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121572/is-there-such-an-x-that-both-2-fracx3-and-3-fracx2-are-simul).

Do there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}^+ \setminus \{1\}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ such that:

- $\displaystyle \frac{\log a}{\log b} \not \in \mathbb{Q}$
- $a^x$ and $b^x$ are both rational

The original question seems very hard. This question could be just as hard, but maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative answer follows from the [four exponentials conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_exponentials_conjecture). Indeed, assuming $x$ and $\frac{\log a}{\log b}$ are irrational, pairs $1,x$ and $\log a,\log b$ are linearly independent. The conjecture then implies that one of
$$\begin{align*}
e^{1\log a} &=a\\
e^{1\log b} &=b\\
e^{x\log a} &=a^x\\
e^{x\log b} &=b^x\end{align*}$$
is transcendental. Hence, for $a,b$ rational, $a^x,b^x$ can't be both rational.

It should be noted, however, that the four exponentials conjecture is wide open, even though we have proven some [very similar results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_exponentials_theorem#Five_exponentials_theorem). Indeed, even the question of whether integrality of $2^x,3^x$ implies rationality of $x$ (which is a special case of your question) is [well-known and open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_exponentials_theorem#Five_exponentials_theorem).