# Rigidity of logarithms of positive integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

The following question is from my colleague. It seems to be emerged considering some elementary number theory problem. This is NOT as exercise or problem in published material although it may looks like. Consider the following equation of positive integers $a$, $b$, $x$, $y$, and a real number $r$.
$$ \log_a x= \log_b y =r \quad (\ast)$$
Can we expect some rigidity of the condition like the following

> Suppose that ($\ast$) holds for some positive integers $a$, $b$, $x$, $y$ and an *irrational* number $r$. Then we must have that $\log_a b$ is *rational*.

At first I guess I can solve this shortly. But after trying some quick attacks I realized that this may be harder than it looks.

Comment: If you had some failed attempts, it is worth mentioning them, to prevent others from repeating these.

Comment: I believe that implication must be false, since it implies that the log to base b of x, which equals the log to base a of x divided by the log to base a of b, is irrational, as the quotient of an irrational number by a rational one. But  many counterexamples exist, e.g. any case where b and x are equal.

Comment: @Simon Good observed, but can you show that such a counterexample can actually satisfy $"(*)"$ ?

Comment: No idea whether it helps, but $r$ must be even transcendental, if $"(*)"$ holds. Otherwise $x=a^r$ would be transcendental because of the Gelfond-Schneider-theorem.

Comment: Good point Peter !

Comment: In fact, the problem seems to be hard !

Comment: This is essentially the four exponentials conjecture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_exponentials_conjecture). It is open even for $a = 2$ and $b = 3$.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17560/if-2x-and-3x-are-integers-must-x-be-as-well,  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121572/is-there-such-an-x-that-both-2-fracx3-and-3-fracx2-are-simul/3132733#3132733

Comment: Many thanks to user670344.